# Bot Framework Composer Combobox Add

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

How do I put Combobox in the Bot framework generator? Is it possible to write with JSON in Adaptive Card?

I wonder your opinion.

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do?